# How can I make SourceInsight understand smart pointers?

Tags: c++, boost, source-insight

If my code uses smart pointers, navigation and completion don't work with SourceInsight. For example with this simple example code:

```
class test {
public:
    void fun(){}
};

int main() {
    boost::scoped_ptr<test> a;
    a->fun();
    return 0;
}
```

When I click `fun()` in `main` , SourceInsight tells me *"symbol not found"*.

Is there something I should do to fix that, or does SourceInsight have limitations?

Comment: class test{
public:
 void fun(){}
};

int main()
{
 boost::scoped_ptr<test> a;
 a.fun();
}

Comment: Shouldn't this be `a->fun();`?

Comment: Does this compile? What is the name of your class? Why click here?

Comment: that just a example,click a->func() source insight can jump to function void fun() of the class test.and I just edit in SI ,have not compile.

Comment: I've reworded the question. I don't think it's broad. I don't think it's off-topic. **Voted to reopen**. Sadly, I never heard about SourceInsight and I'm not sure it will be popular. My gut says this is just a limitation of the tool, but perhaps someone else knows!

Comment: _For the code given_, the behavior seems entirely reasonable. There's no `#include` for boost, so how is SourceInsight to know that `boost::scoped_ptr` is a smart pointer?

Comment: thanks sehe.it  is popular in some areas.

Comment: Erm. So, let's make that suggestion constructive: Did you include `boost/scoped_ptr.hpp` (and does SourceInsight know how to find the include)?

Answer (score 2):

So I've given this a try. Downloaded, virus-scanned, signed up for free trial, installed wine, run!

Now, I can make SourceInsight import the symbols from the Boost directories: [image]

I then enter the path to my Boost directory: `Z:\home\sehe\custom\boost\`
[image]

Processing takes a minute or two:

[image]

Seems ok:

[image]

---

Now if you import these symbols in your project:

[image]

You *will* find you can navigate to `boost::scoped_ptr<>` just fine (I double-clicked on the `a` in the declaration of `a`):

[image]

But it will not find references to `fun`:

[image]

Finds only the declaration:

[image]

Of course you can use simple string search, but that wasn't the point.

Here's the HTML export: https://s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow-sehe/f14b4ee2-9b4d-49cd-893d-cf69372dd586/HTML/test.cpp.html

[image]

### Conclusion

It seems this is a limitation of SourceInsight, not due to misconfiguration.

Comment: I  think so, as if it does not recognize "<>" as "()" in macros. Otherwise it can be configured